# How to prove this sentence?

Tags: prime-factorization, natural-numbers

Suppose $n$ is composite. Consider a prime $q$ that is a factor of $n$ and let $(q^k) || n$. Then $q$ does not divide
$$\dbinom{n}{q}$$

Why it is correct?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Why introduce $k$?  In any case, $\binom 42=6$.

Comment: Did you type this correctly?  What do you mean by $q^k\mid\mid n$?  What is $\mid\mid$?  What is $k$?  Do you mean $q^k\mid n$ for some integer $k>1$?  Do you mean $q^k\nmid n$ for any $k>1$?

Comment: @JMoravitz sometimes $q^k || n$ is used to mean that $q^k \mid n$ and $q^{k+1} \nmid n$.

Comment: Yes that probably the same thankyou

Comment: Note the differences in the question... in particular we're showing that $q^k$, not $q$, is not a factor of $\binom{n}{q}$.  lulu's comment is a counterexample otherwise.